# How viable are multi-colour decks in Digimon?

Tags: deck-building

The recently-English released Digimon TCG has a lot of interesting things going on, but one thing I can't determine just from reading card effects is how viable multi-colour decks are. The game footage I've watched is completely dominated by single-colour decks that work towards getting out a single level 7 Digimon.

So, is building a deck around using two or more colours viable and what are the implications of that on how you can play the game?

Comment: Just to clarify, but you're asking about the new Digimon TCG, and not the one from the 90s, right? It looks like there's been like two or three completely separate TCGs associated with the property.

Answer (score 1):

On the first hand, **YES**.

In the current BT & future ones(most likely), multi-colored decks are/will be strong in the meta of the game.

> The game footage I've watched is completely dominated by single-colour decks that work towards getting out a single level 7 Digimon.

Sure thing, most of the decks are focused on playing big cards and then stomp the enemy with almost unkillable digimons.

But,have you heard of the **rookie rush**(RR)? In a lot of championships, the RR won just by spawning rookies.Also in some cases the  RR deck is also multi-coloured.

Not all decks are focused on getting to Lv7 digimons to stomp enemy SecurityChecks, some are just spawing little ones to be quick in getting as much SC hits in one turn as possible, then in next turn(as they are low on memory cost) spawn some more, rinse and repeat.